# Perl Translation

Tags: perl, transactions, tr

I want to do something like this

```
$string ='4791';
$string =~ tr/4791/(ma)(laya)(lam)(_baasha)/;
```

should give me

```
$string='malayalam_baasha';
```

i.e replace each character with n other characters. n may be different for each character.

Is there a one line solution for this translation ?

Comment: yes, but it will be a long line, and one hard to maintain too. it also will not involve `tr`.

Comment: you want it, you got it (but I am too ashamed to post it as an answer): `perl -l -e'for (@ARGV) { $n=3; $a=ord(a); s{(\d)}{join "", map { chr($a+$_+$n*$1)} (0..$n-1)}eg; print }' 0123` $n is the number of characters for each number in the replacement string

Comment: Is this a generic solution ? See edit in the question.

Comment: it is not a generic solution, it answered your original question. It's mostly there to illustrate the point I was making above: DON'T DO IT IN ONE LINE. Wanting to do something like this in one line is not a good idea. We're not usually paid to write perl golf.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you always want to replace a single character with a specific string...

```
my %Replacement = (
    '0' => 'abc',
    '1' => 'def',
    '2' => 'ghi',
    '3' => 'jkl',
    # ... whatever others you like ...
);

my $String = '0123';
print "$String\n"; # Prints "0123"
$String =~ s{(.)}
            {exists($Replacement{$1}) ? $Replacement{$1} : $1}egx;
print "$String\n"; # Prints "abcdefghijkl"
```

Just make an entry in %Replacement for each character you want to swap out.

Re-reading your question, no, this isn't on one line, though it can be written as such (though messily) if you like.  Constraining it to a single line will really kind of depend on how many different exchanges you want to have, though.  After a certain point, it's going to get ugly.

Answer (score 3):

The right answer is Brian Gerard's, but it can be done in one fairly short and almost readable line:

```
$string =~ s/(.)/{1 => "_baasha", 4 => "ma", 7 => "laya", 9 => "lam"}->{$1}/ge;
```

or one short unreadable line:

```
$string =~ s/(.)/{4,ma=>7,laya=>9,lam=>1,"_baasha"}->{$1}/ge;
```

or even shorter, but a bit more readable:

```
$string =~ s/(.)/qw(a _baasha a a ma a a laya a lam)[$1]/ge;
```

or the shortest I could get it (this one won't work with `strict` turned on):

```
$string =~ s/(.)/(a,_baasha,a,a,ma,a,a,laya,a,lam)[$1]/ge;
```

Comment: did you mean actually {4,ma=>7,laya=>9,lam=>1,"_baasha"} or would it rather be {4=>'ma',7=>'laya',9=>'lam',1=>'_baasha'} for better syntactical sugar?

Comment: @arhak nope, it is taking advantage of the fact that `=>` and `,` are both just comma operators. `=>` just auto-quotes its LHS if it is a bareword.  I used that feature to make it shorter (I don't need to quote most of the strings).  I did say it was unreadable.

Comment: @chas-owens ok, I thought you might be intentionally saving characters, but that's raw laziness over readability. Reminds me of Meyer saying "arr@3" is one character shorter than "arr[3]" (bad example, since in this case it is actually more readable, but well.. for such a verbose language a single character less wouldn't make the difference)...

Answer (score 1):

This

```perl
($i=0) || (@tr = qw |abc def ghi jkl| ) && (@string = map { $tr[$i++] } split //,'0123') && ($string =join '',@string);
```

OR

```
( %tr = ( 0 => 'abc' , 1 => 'def' , 2 => 'ghi' , 3 => 'jkl' ) ) && (@string = map { $tr{$_} } split //,'0123') && ($string =join '',@string);
```

should work! But I wouldn't use it!!

Comment: Why are you splitting the mapping and joining steps?  Heck, even the hash creation doesn't need to be a different step: `$string = join "", map { { 0 => "abc", 1 => "def", 2 = > "ghi", 3 => "jkl"}->{$_} } split //, $string;`